# Complexity of bucket sort with a known upper bound?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, big-o

Say we have an array that we know all the elements are 0...2n and are not ordered.

If we use a bucket sort algorithm with the complexity of O(n+k) where k is the range of the elements, which in this case is 2n, would the complexity to sort this array be Θ(n)?

My rationale is that the runtime is O(n + 2n), which si the same as O(3n), and since 3 is just a coefficient the complexity would be Θ(n).

Is this analysis accurate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your analysis is correct. Counting sort's runtime is Θ(n + k), where n is the number of elements and k is the number of buckets. If the maximum value is cn for any fixed constant c, then the runtime of counting sort will be Θ(n), as you've mentioned.

Hope this helps!

Comment: You didn't prove a lower bound, so how can this analysis be correct? Or rather OP originally quoted it as O(n+k), but if it is indeed Θ(n + k), fine

Comment: @clwhisk- Bucket sort is Theta(n + k), even though the OP quoted it as O(n + k).